# i have two different Stored procedures. I need to enter those result sets into an excel in different sheets automatically

Tags: sql, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two different Stored procedures. By executing both of them i will get result sets from both the SPs. I need to enter those result sets into an excel in different sheets automatically. please suggest me a process.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/

This is a good website link to look at above

Comment: Thanks for the link...but this didn't answer my query